# PrivateFontCollection fails on appharbor

Tags: c#, fonts, appharbor

I am trying to load a custom font (ttf file) and draw into an image with the Graphics object. This code runs fine locally:

```
PrivateFontCollection fonts = new PrivateFontCollection();

string path = context.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Futura LT Bold.ttf");

if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Font file is not deployed: " + path);
}

fonts.AddFontFile(path);
```

However when run on appharbor, the call to AddFontFile fails with the exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Font 'Futura LT Book' does not support style 'Regular'.
at System.Drawing.Font.CreateNativeFont()
at System.Drawing.Font.Initialize(FontFamily family, Single emSize, FontStyle style, GraphicsUnit unit, Byte gdiCharSet, Boolean gdiVerticalFont)
at System.Drawing.Font..ctor(FontFamily family, Single emSize)
at LumenboxWeb.Controllers.GalleryController.FontTest() in d:\temp\h5oqslma.udd\input\src\LumenboxWeb\Controllers\GalleryController.cs:line 59
at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
```

I have tried different fonts, and they all work locally, but none work on appharbor.

Is it possible to load fonts dynamically on appharbor?

Comment: Well, there's a method named FontTest() and the test failed.  Change the test or avoid that font.

Comment: FontTest is not a unit test. I am just using that controller action to reproduce this problem. I need to do this in production code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string path = context.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Futura LT Bold.ttf");
fonts.AddFontFile(path);
```

You can tell from the .ttf name why this is throwing an exception.  Note the "Bold" in the file name. This makes the odds that you can create an instance of that font with FontStyle = Regular rather low.  But with good odds that FontStyle = Bold will work.

A typeface normally has *multiple* .ttf files, one each for each FontStyle.  You'd have to add the other files as well, assuming you have them.

Comment: Yes that was the problem, not sure why it was working on my local PC though and not appharbor. Anyway this fixed it. Thanks